# Python subprocess module - variable scope

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

My python script have weird behavior. So, I have python script A, which calls another script B many times. For calling B, I'm using *subprocess* module.

Snippets of script A:

```
for i in range(0,10000):
    parameters = []
    parameters.append("B")
    result = subprocess.call(parameters)
```

Snippets of script B:

```
testdata = some_logic
if testdata:
    function_1()
else:
    function_2()
```

So, script A will calls script B many times. After some tests, I noticed that variable **testdata** doesn't have expected value for current running script B. Is it somehow possible in running script B, that variable **testdata** has value from previous call B? What is scope for variable **testdata** in this case? Thanks for advice. Cheers

Comment: As a side note, you may want to change the title.  `mutliprocessing` is a completely different module where (with a little effort), you can share state between processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subprocess.call` starts a child process.  That process knows nothing about what is going on in `A` or how many times it has been called -- All it knows is what commandline arguments you've passed to it.  In this case, you're always calling `'B'` with no commandline arguments since `parameters` always equals `['B']` when you call `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Ok. What will happen if I have more instances of script A running in same time?

Comment: Each instance of script A will spawn instances of script B -- All which know nothing of each other.